# How to fix SMTPSenderRefused at /register/ in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm developing an application in Django with a friend, and we've implemented account activation functionality by sending an activation email with a link. Unfortunately, we've encountered an issue where I can register successfully, and the activation email is sent without any errors, but my friend receives an error like the one shown in the image below upon registration and clicking 'Register.'

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYPFD.png)

This is my code in settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_FROM = os.environ.get('EMAIL_LOGIN')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_LOGIN')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = os.environ.get('EMAIL_LOGIN')
```

How can we resolve this issue?